# ubuntu: prepare a server, let remote login GUI

Tags: remote-desktop

Our company is limited in web browsing(security reason),
only a few IP can connect to the internet.

so I need prepare a server, let user using this server for web browsing.

only one person can use it at a time,
And I want the users can login this server remotely and concurrently.

Current I use VNC server, only one user can use at a time,
What are other solutions? remote login and start a new X client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11 is specifically designed for this, no need to deal with VNC.  The easiest would be to use [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run as many VNC servers at once as your system has resources to handle.

Comment: different user need different GUI.

Comment: Yes, you can run a separate desktop on each VNC server, and run each one as a different user.

Comment: I have 10 user and this server is my working PC and I have a virtualbox running... so I need login and logout.

Comment: I need evaluate this solution first, and then I can ask a standalone PC for this job.